# load mp4 video by query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I need to load a mp4 video by a query string. Using jquery my code does not update the video source. If I place the example video url in the html5 source id it works without the JQuery. My task is to open the page with the correct video loaded.

Problem was code didn't see JS source.. Also defined variable with $ when I shouldn't have. Now it works..

```
  <video id='videoPlayer' width="640" height="480" controls="controls">
      <source id='mp4Source' src="" type="video/mp4" />  
    </video>  
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">-->
  <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    // theVid will be populated by query string, for testing it's hard coded.
    //var theVid = 'http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4';
    var theVid = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4';

    var player = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
    var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');

    player.pause();

      // Now simply set the 'src' attribute of the mp4Vid variable!!!!
      // (...using the jQuery library in this case)

    $(mp4Vid).attr('src', theVid);
    player.load();
    //player.show();
    player.play();   

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#mp4Source').attr('src', theVid);
```

You didn't set the source to html you listed. Try that.

Comment: In this case I figured it out about an hour after posting, Since I couldn't answer it for 8 hours, I just edited it with the working code.  theVid is the source with the URL working. My issue was it wasn't seeing the script source at the bottom, moving it to the top helped.